# Splitting in Short exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-extensions

I am trying to find whether $\{1\}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow \{1\}$ splits. My conjecture is it is not as we cannot find a non-zero group homomorphism from $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. If my conjecture is correct, can we tweak the above sequence so that it splits?

Comment: By the way with abelian groups, denoting the operation by $+$, it's typical to refer to the trivial group as $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 9):

Is not split:

If it is we get $\Bbb R=\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z$ which is not possible, because there is no element of finite order in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @ Hamou $\Bbb R$ is connected, but $\Bbb Z$ is not connected.

Answer (score 3):

The sequence $0 \to \mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}\to 0$ splits.

To have a split one you need the subgroup to be divisible ( a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector subspace).

Comment: Oh, so $\Bbb R \cong \Bbb Q \oplus \Bbb R / \Bbb Q$? Interesting...

Comment: A subgroup of a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space is a direct summand if and only if it is in fact a subspace, that is, a divisible subgroup.  Note that $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space.